# Java Memory Model consistency guarantees

Tags: java

I'm currently reading the book *The Art of Multiprocessor Programming*, 2<sup>nd</sup> edition. According to its appendix on the Java Memory Model (A.3.2), `volatile` fields (as well as any amount of fields where all accesses to these fields are guarded by the same lock) are linearizable. Now according to my lecture, which is heavily based on the book, the following is true:

1. If we have a shared java memory system where all accesses to shared data are guarded by the same lock, then all well-formed histories produced by this system are linearizable.
2. If we have a shared java memory system where all accesses to shared data are made on volatile variables, then all well-formed histories produced by this system are sequentially consistent but not necessarily linearizable.

I've been trying my best to find an example that satisfies the second assumptions and which is not linearizable but I couldn't find one. I think that the second point is indeed linearizable (referring to *The Art of Multiprocessor Programming*).
I hope someone could tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: Thinking out loud, could it be that variables not marked as volatile could be read from a cache/register, and a write may not be reflected in a successive read?

Comment: Of course, but wouldn't that be a data race since we're speaking of shared variables where reads and writes are not ordered by the happens-before order?

Comment: I guess in the second example, "but now linearizable" has a typo.  Surely it should be "but *not* linearizable", else the comparison does not make sense.  I guess the second alternative also implicitly assumes that the shared-variable accesses are not guarded by a lock.

Comment: I guess the second alternative also means that program histories are not *guaranteed* to be linearizable. It can't mean that every such history exhibits behavior that contradicts linearizability.

Comment: Side note: the edition (first, I guess) of *The Art of Multiprocessor Programming* that I am looking at does contain comments along lines similar to those presented in the question, but they do not appear in an appendix, and Appendix 3.2 of that edition isn't even about Java.

Comment: I corrected all misleading formulations and apologize for that. My copy is the second edition.